# How to set -JlopCount = <Forever> in Jmeter non-GUI mode?

Tags: jmeter

Goal is to set the following and run a test plan with a "Thread Group" and "CSV Data Set Config" with 1000 lines/user accounts. So in 20 mins i want 10 threads to go through my 1000 line long csv file.

I set these settings in GUI mode and it does what i want:

Thread Group .

1. num of threads - 10 .
2. LoopCount=Forever .
3. scheduler=on .
4. duration=7200 .

"CSV Data Set Config"

1. Recycle on EOF? - False
2. Stop thread of EOF? - False
3. Sharing mode=All Threads

The problem is that i can't reproduce these setting from non_gui mode. I run it as follows and it only goes through # of csv lines equaling the # of threads set. So if i set 20 threads it will go through 20 lines of a file and exit.

1. -Jseconds=1200
2. -JthreadCount=20
3. -JcsvFile=../../user_files/j2kUsers.csv
4. -JloopCount=???

Answer (score 0):

Use `-1` as the property value, Thread Group has a [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) under the hood and as per documentation:

> The value -1 is equivalent to checking the `Forever` toggle.

You can also put the values to *user.properties* file like:

```
seconds=1200
threadCound=20
etc.
```

to avoid entering the values each time you run the script, the values van be [overriden via -J command line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override) at any time.

More information: [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/)